# Laravel Orchid Many to Many relation field in Resource

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, orchid

I have two model: Colleague and Work.

Colleague.php

```
class Colleague extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, AsSource, Filterable, Attachable;
    protected $primaryKey = 'slug';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public function works() : BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Work::class);
    }
}
```

Work.php

```
class Work extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, AsSource, Filterable, Attachable;
    public function colleagues() : BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Colleague::class);
    }
}
```

I have migrations for Work, Colleague and a table for colleague_work.
colleagues migration

```
Schema::create('colleagues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('secondName');
            $table->string('firstName');
            $table->string('lastName');
            $table->string('jobTitle');
            $table->string('socialLinkName');
            $table->string('socialLink');
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->string('cover');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

works migration

```
Schema::create('works', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('workTitle');
            $table->string('workCompany');
            $table->string('workType');
            $table->string('workThumbnail');
            $table->string('workSizeType');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and colleague_work table

```
Schema::create('colleague_work', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('work_id');
            $table->string('colleague_slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In Laravel Orchid I create a resource WorkResource for creating and editing the works.

WorkResource.php

```
class WorkResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = Work::class;

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            Input::make('workTitle')
                ->required()
                ->title('Work name')
                ->placeholder('Work Name'),
            Input::make('workCompany')
                ->required()
                ->title('Nickname')
                ->placeholder('24mkk'),
            Input::make('workType')
                ->required()
                ->title('Work type')
                ->placeholder('site'),
            Picture::make('workThumbnail')
                 ->required()
                 ->title('Thumbnail'),
            Relation::make('colleagues.')
                ->fromModel(Colleague::class, 'slug')
                ->multiple()
                ->title('Colleagues'),
            Select::make('workSizeType')
                ->required()
                ->title('Work size type')
                ->options([
                    'sm'   => 'Small',
                    'md' => 'Medium',
                    'xl' => 'Big',
                ]),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the columns displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @return TD[]
     */
    public function columns(): array
    {
        return [
            TD::make('id'),

            TD::make('created_at', 'Date of creation')
                ->render(function ($model) {
                    return $model->created_at->toDateTimeString();
                }),

            TD::make('updated_at', 'Update date')
                ->render(function ($model) {
                    return $model->updated_at->toDateTimeString();
                }),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the sights displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @return Sight[]
     */
    public function legend(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the resource.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

When I create new work I have this error:
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'colleague' in 'field list'`
`insert into` works `(`workTitle`,` workCompany`,` workType`,` workThumbnail`,` colleague`,` workSizeType`,` updated_at`,` created_at`) values (Work1, 24mkk, site, 123, ?, sm, 2024-03-20 18:28:13, 2024-03-20 18:28:13)`

What I need to do for adding many-to-many right?